# image not loaded from url on v-img on vuetify

Tags: vuetify.js

Im facing a problem using v-img from vuetify,
this is my code example:

```
{{showPreviewUrl}} <!-- showPreviewUrl = "/getimage/imageuuid" path is loaded ok -->

<!-- my problem is here, image not loaded -->>
<v-img :src="showPreviewUrl" contain></v-img>  

<!-- image loaded OK -->>
<v-img src="https://picsum.photos/510/300?random" aspect-ratio="1.4" contain></v-img> 

<!-- image loaded OK -->>
<img :src="showPreviewUrl">
```

the src is an image, it loads on an "img" tag, but not on v-img

Comment: For the Vite environment, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75655533)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<v-img :src="require(`@${showPreviewUrl}`)" contain></v-img>
```